# How to convert numpy array from 3D (4,1,10) to (10,1,4)

Tags: python, python-3.x

if i have a numpy array with shape (4,1,10) how can i create another array having same elements but with shape (10,1,4). Because i tried transpose function and it didn't help. i tried separately transposing still no luck. could anyone tell me what am i doing wrong in the following code.

```
import pandas
import numpy

dataframe = pandas.read_csv('LBMP_PJM2017.csv', delimiter=',', usecols= 
[4,5,6,7,8], engine='python')
features = dataframe[:10]
labels = numpy.array(features['TWI Zonal LBMP'])
print(labels)

attribute1 = numpy.array(features['TWI Zonal Losses'])
attribute1 = numpy.transpose(attribute1)
attribute2 = numpy.array(features['DAM Zonal LBMP'])
attribute2 = numpy.transpose(attribute2)
attribute3 = numpy.array(features['DAM Zonal Losses'])
attribute3 = numpy.transpose(attribute3)
attribute4 = numpy.array(features['DAM Zonal Congestion'])
attribute4 = numpy.transpose(attribute4)
features.drop('TWI Zonal LBMP', axis=1)
features = numpy.array(features)

data_x = numpy.array([[attribute1[:]],[attribute2[:]],[attribute3[:]], 
[attribute4[:]]])
print('--dataX--',data_x.shape,'--dataX--')
...
```

Output:

```
.
:
--dataX-- (4, 1, 10) --dataX--
```

Comment: Did you try `data_x.reshape((10, 1, 4))` ?

Comment: It worked thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use numpy **reshape()** utility.

Supposing you have `my_old_array` with shape `(4, 1, 10)`, you can do:

```
my_new_array = my_old_array.reshape(10, 1, 4)
```

Full documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html